# $n^2 + 7n + 1$ is odd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, parity

Prove that for any integer $n$, the integer $n^2 + 7n + 1$ is odd.

I have  $n=2k+1$ for some $k\in Z$

I really do not how to do this problem. any help in understanding would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are supposing that $n$ is odd (by writing $n=2k+1$ what you actually want to show is $n^2+7n+1$ is the same as $2(\text{something})+1$. Try setting $n:=2k+1$ as you have and seeing if you can jig $n^2+7n+1$ into the form above. Then (as you've only done the odd cases) set $n:=2k$ and cover your even cases of $n$. What you want to show is: "suppose $n$ is odd, then $n^2+7n+1$ is odd" AND "suppose $n$ is even, then $n^2+7n+1$ is odd" and then you're done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only two scenarios here: $n$ is odd or $n$ is even. That alone is enough to determine whether $n^2 + 7n + 1$ is odd or even.

- If $n$ is odd, then so is $n^2$, as well as $7n$. Then $n^2 + 7n$ is even, because two odd numbers add up to an even number. But then there's the $+ 1$, which makes the number odd again.
- If $n$ is even, then so is $n^2$, as well as $7n$. Two even numbers also add up to an even number. But again we have the $+ 1$, which then makes the number odd.

Try it with a few specific odd and even values of $n$. I'll do two for you:

- $n = 1$, then we have $1 + 7 + 1 = 9$, which is odd.
- $n = 2$, then we have $4 + 14 + 1 = 19$, which is also odd.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**: You should be able to fill in the the following blanks and justify each claim made. We start by noting that $$n^2+7n=n(n+7).$$ If $n$ is an integer, then either $n$ or $n+7$ must be _____ and the other must be _____. Hence, $n(n+7)$ must be _____, and so....

Answer (score 2):

$n^2 + 7n + 1= n(n+1)+6n+1$

$n(n+1)=2\binom{n}{2}$ and so is even.

$6n+1=2(3n)+1$ and so is odd.

So the sum is odd.

Answer (score 1):

You can distinguish two cases: $n=2k$ or $n=2k+1$ ($n$ even or odd, respectively) and substituting in $n^2+7n+1$ you should be able to rewrite the result as $2l+1$ for a certain $l$ in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $n$ is odd, then is $n^2$ odd or even? what about $7n$? Ask the same questions if $n$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: plug in $n=2k+1$ into the form of the number you have, expand and show you get something of the form $2\cdot (some integer)+1$. Repeat by plugging in $n=2k$. Option 2: Do you know that the sum of three odd numbers is odd? Do you know that the square of an odd number is odd? Do you know that the product of two odd numbers is odd? What about even numbers?

Comment: I plugged 2k+1 back into the equation. (2k+1)^2 + 7 (2k+1) +1                                      Should I factor it? 4k^2 + 18k + 9?

Comment: just try. If you are going to be so timid about trying and ask for validation for each and every step you're not going to get too far (in life).

Comment: If I knew what I was doing I would not be asking for help

Comment: if you have an idea for something to try out, just go ahead and try it out rather than ask someone if you should try it out. That's how you learn.

Comment: That's how *some* people learn. Other people need a lot more spoonfeeding, and it seems to me like the spoonfeeding needed in this case is not terribly onerous on the one with the spoon.

Comment: @cole my comments are meant with the best intention and I apologise if you experience my answer and comments as unhelpful or annoying. I'm responding based on my philosophy of learning and truly mean to help you. Please feel free to ignore my answer, if you so wish. I'll just say that from your question ("... should I factor it?...") it seems you do have some idea of what to do. That is why I replied the way I did, to encourage you to figure it out for yourself. Had you asked "should I integrate, and then divide by $\pi$" I would have spoon-fed you differently. I don't think you need spoons.

Answer (score 0):

$$n^2+7n+1=n(n+7)+1.$$

Note that:

- if $n$ is even, $n+7$ is odd.
- if $n$ is odd, $n+7$ is even.

Thus $n(n+7)$ is the product of an odd and an even term, which is even. Thus $n(n+7)+1$ is an even term plus $1$, which is **odd**.